Swagger getting generated with allOff and oneOff, leading to cyclic API doc
I am using spring boot 3.2.7 version. I have rest endpoint which accepts RequestDTO as request body.
RequestDTO is defined as sealed interface as below for hierarchy.
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ARequestDTO.class, name = "A")})
@Schema(oneOf = {ARequestDTO.class})
public sealed interface RequestDTO permits ARequestDTO {
  String type();
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "subType")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DRequestDTO.class, name = "D"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CRequestDTO.class, name = "C")
})
@Schema(oneOf = {CRequestDTO.class, DRequestDTO.class})
sealed interface ARequestDTO extends RequestDTO permits CRequestDTO, DRequestDTO {
  String type();

  String subType();
}

record CRequestDTO(String type, String subType) implements ARequestDTO {}

record DRequestDTO(String type, String userId, String subType) implements ARequestDTO {}




With this the swagger generate a cyclic api doc, as below:
{
  "paths": {
    "/private/api/v1/test/as": {
      "post": {
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "oneOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestDTO"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "ARequestDTO": {
        "required": [
          "subType"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "discriminator": {
          "propertyName": "subType"
        },
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestDTO"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "subType": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CRequestDTO"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DRequestDTO"
          }
        ]
      },
      "CRequestDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ARequestDTO"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "subType": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "DRequestDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ARequestDTO"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "userId": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "subType": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "RequestDTO": {
        "required": [
          "type"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "discriminator": {
          "propertyName": "type"
        },
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ARequestDTO"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}


Not sure how allOf is being added. Please help to figure this out.
